# Issues Calling data Constructor in Haskell

Tags: haskell, constructor, functional-programming, declarative, hugs

I am attempting to write my own polymorphic list type, List a, to act as the default library list. I believe that the code is correct, however I cannot seem to call it successfully in Hugs98. What would be the correct way to call the function and count the length of a non empty list, using the type List a?

```
My Haskell Code is:
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)

len :: List a -> Int
len Nil = 0
len (Cons _ xs) = 1 + len xs
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ``len (1 `Cons` 2 `Cons` 3 `Cons` Nil)`` for example, if you put an ``infixr 8 `Cons` `` declaration in the file. What did you try, and how did hugs complain about that?

Comment: The `[a]` type, `[]` and `:` , the associated `[item1,item2,item3]` bracket-and-comma syntax, and all the `[1..5]` style ellipsis forms are built into the language itself.  You can't simply replace Haskell's implementation of lists with your own.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you've saved that code in a file called Lists.hs

Here's how you can call your `len` function in Hugs.

```
Main> :l Lists
Main> len Nil
0
Main> len (Cons 1 Nil)
1
Main> len (Cons 'a' Nil)
1
Main> len (Cons 'a' (Cons 'b' Nil))
2
Main> len (Cons 'a' (Cons 'b' (Cons 'c' Nil)))
3
```

The brackets are a bit ugly, though. Here's a way of making it nicer:

```
infixr 5 :.
data List a = Nil | a :. (List a) 
    deriving Show
```

The `infixr` line tells Hugs that the constructor `:.` should associate to the right, so that there are implicit brackets to the right, this means that

```
'a' :. 'b' :. Nil  =  'a' :. ('b' :. Nil)
```

If you don't put this, Hugs will assume that `:.` associates to the left, so it would think

```
'a' :. 'b' :. Nil  =  ('a' :. 'b') :. Nil
```

Which doesn't make sense - you'd get

```
Main> 'a' :. 'b' :. Nil
ERROR - Type error in application
*** Expression     : 'a' :. 'b'
*** Term           : 'b'
*** Type           : Char
*** Does not match : List a
```

or more confusingly, if it's numbers, it'll try to make a number out of a list:

```
Main> 1 :. 2 :. Nil
ERROR - Cannot infer instance
*** Instance   : Num (List a)
*** Expression : 1 :. 2 :. Nil
```

Anyway, we did the `infixr 5 :.` thing, so that won't happen. I picked a precedence of 5, because that's what `:` has in the standard prelude. Now we can edit `len` to cope with the new definition:

```
len :: List a -> Int
len Nil = 0
len (_ :. xs) = 1 + len xs
```

so that you get

```
Main> len (4 :. 5 :. 6:. Nil)
3
```

or if you prefer,

```
Main> len $ 4 :. 5 :. 6:. Nil
3
```

(You could have done

```
infixr 5 `Cons`
```

instead, but I don't think that's as nice.)

Comment: It was nice to use an old friend Hugs again. I'd forgotten how fast Hugs is loading and interpreting, and how much I like it to automatically use the latest saved version of my .hs files. I remember Gofer too.... sigh. I don't really miss Orwell, though!